# DataFrames.jl - selecting columns by type or name substring

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am new to Julia.

In DataFrames.jl, is there a way to select all variables of a given type, or all variables with a given substring in their names?

For instance in R we have:

```
df %>% select_if(is.numeric)

df %>% select(matches("_some_string_"))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For selection of variables with a given substring use:

```
select(df, r"_some_string_")
```

actually it is much more powerful than a substring - it can be any `Regex`.

For selection of variables of a given element type this is more tricky. The issue is that in Julia you have much more flexibility than in R here. E.g. you can have eltype of `Any`, but the vector still contains only numbers.

Therefore you can either write:

```
select(df, findall(col -> eltype(col) <: Float64, eachcol(df)))
```

of course this is restrictive here, you can change `Float64` to something like `Real`, `Number` or `Union{Missing, Int}` depending on what you want to select exactly.
or write:

```
select(df, findall(col -> all(v -> v isa Float64, col), eachcol(df)))
```

this time you check not the element type of the container but actual type of stored values.

Here is a quick example of the difference:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=[1.0], b=Any[1.0], c=[1])
1×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ a       │ b   │ c     │
│     │ Float64 │ Any │ Int64 │
├─────┼─────────┼─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0     │ 1.0 │ 1     │

julia> select(df, findall(col -> eltype(col) <: Float64, eachcol(df)))
1×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ a       │
│     │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0     │

julia> select(df, findall(col -> all(v -> v isa Float64, col), eachcol(df)))
1×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a       │ b   │
│     │ Float64 │ Any │
├─────┼─────────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0     │ 1.0 │
```

Comment: Can also use `nonmissingtype(eltype(col))` to get just the `T` part of the column's type, if it's a `Union{Missing,T}`

Answer (score 0):

Another option to `select` columns with certain substrings is using `Cols` and `contains.` to find columns with a certain substring. Here is some reproducible code:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col3 = 3)
1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ col1   col2   col3  
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      2      3

julia> select(df, Cols(contains.("2")))
1×1 DataFrame
 Row │ col2  
     │ Int64 
─────┼───────
   1 │     2
```